Issue when using cortex docker image in kubernetes
I'm trying to create a SOC with open source solution :
cortex / the hive / misp / shuffle / wazuh .
I'm encountering an issue with cortex where i've created a manifest for kubernetes based a docker hub official one .
I've successfully deployed it and it's working i can access interface and run analysis , my  cortex deployment can run docker image since i've shared the docker.sock of my host to my container as a volume .
But when i run any analysis like virustotal or anything i got an issue where the element to analyse isn't passed as parameter into the docker container here the error code i'm having inside de docker container :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/worker/VirusTotal/virustotal.py", line 415, in <module>
    VirusTotalAnalyzer().run()
  File "/worker/VirusTotal/virustotal.py", line 24, in __init__
    Analyzer.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cortexutils/analyzer.py", line 18, in __init__
    Worker.__init__(self, job_directory, secret_phrases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cortexutils/worker.py", line 35, in __init__
    self._input = json.load(sys.stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)



Found out the issue. I did an incorrect mount volume between docker execution and my k8s volume:
Cortex is on a k8s node host that have docker installed.
step 1 - I passed my docker.sock from my k8s node host
step 2 - cortex launching docker container on my k8s host
step 3 - I misconfigured the volume I had config a shared volume between k8s cortex and docker host execution to have access to the report generated
step 4 - to do that you need to have the variable docker_job_directory that points to a volume inside k8s host and mount it:
         env:
            - name: docker_job_directory
              value: "/tmp/cortex-jobs"
         volumeMounts:
              - name: docker-job-directory
              mountPath: /tmp/cortex-jobs
             volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: "/tmp/cortex-jobs"
          name: docker-job-directory

Don't forget you need also to set the good right on the folder inside node k8s host (the hostpath folder).
